# make an activity extending ListActivity extend BaseScreen

Tags: android, android-listview

I have two activities. ScreenOne.java and ScreenTwo.java.

ScreenOne extends BaseScreen
ScreenTwo extends ListActivity

I want ScreenTwo to extend BaseScreen as the Back button event makes the app crash.

```
this.mainListView = getListView();
```

This is the only line that throws up an error if I change the extension.

The error is:

```
The method getListView() is undefined for the type ScreenTwo.
```

My Back button code:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ScreenThree.class); 
     startActivity(intent); 
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I need one of the following workarounds:

- Make ScreenTwo extend BaseScreen
- An alternative to the "troublesome" line of code
- Override the Back button to start a new activity.

LogCat Output:

```
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Droid.Screens.ScreenTwo
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at com.example.Droid.Services.ScreenService.getCurrentScreen(ScreenService.java:226)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at com.example.Droid.Screens.BaseScreen.processKeyDown(BaseScreen.java:310)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at com.example.Droid.Main.onKeyDown(Main.java:183)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1256)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2078)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1709)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2628)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2603)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1875)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
09-07 11:30:13.419: E/AndroidRuntime(2845): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `@android:id/list` as an ID of ListView, use:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewByID(android.R.id.list);
```

else use:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewByID(R.id.listView); // the id of your listView given in xml file.
```

In this way you don't have to extend the `ListActivity`.

Comment: I tried that and I get the following error: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Droid.Screens.ScreenTwo}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.Droid.Screens.ScreenTwo

Comment: the error is above, and I am have tried both, please see the edit for the logCat

Comment: You might be using the constructor but it isn't an appropriate constructor, or perhaps your constructor is throwing an exception.

Comment: Don't use getBaseContext() instead use YourActivity.this in onKeyDown()

Comment: Your ClassCastException is occurring on this line: com.example.Droid.Services.ScreenService.getCurrentScreen(ScreenService.java:226). Can you post that line?

Comment: return (IBaseScreen)((Main)Engine.getInstance().getMainActivity()).getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();

Comment: This is quite diff to understand. But what I got from this statement is, the activity which you are getting from getCurrentActivity() is not the BaseScreen and hence the ClassCastException has occurred. Why are you Casting you activity as BaseScreen?

Comment: It's seems to be the only way the back button won't crash

Answer (score 0):

`Make ScreenTwo extend BaseScreen`

Only things you need to change are:

in the XML:

remove `id = "@android:id/list"`  for the ListView and make it something like
 `id = "@+id/yourListView"`

and in the Activity instead of using

```
this.mainListView = getListView();
```

use

```
ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourListView);
```

these are the only things you need to change. If you don't get what you wanted after changing these. Then it is because of some other reason, not the Inheritance problem

or else as per your 3rd point use this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

   Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, ScreenThree.class);
   startActivity(setIntent);
}
```

Comment: I guess the problem is elsewhere as this didn't work when I tried it:(

Comment: didn't work!!.. any exceptions?? or works fine but not as expected?

Comment: see the comments below please :)

Comment: then just override the back button pressed. if thats the only reason you want to extend backScreen

Comment: the error shown in the above logCat is what happens when I do that